# how to make terminal rule case insensitive?

Tags: xtext

I have a scenario where a statement/rule can appear anywhere in the whole code. This statement starts with a keyword and if this keyword appears, i need to skip the whole content till i reach ';'.

I tried addressing this by defining a terminal rule as below:
         terminal stmt: 'TEMP' -> ';';

However my whole code is case insensitive and terminal rules are not. How do i make terminal rule case insensitive? Or is there a alternative way in which all my conditions for this statement are satisfied?

Comment: do you want to make a=1 terminal case insensitive or the whole grammar?

Comment: The whole grammar along with terminal rules. I have added the ignorecase to be true for both ScopeProvider and parserGenerator. It is working for all the other rules except terminal rules.

Comment: Hmmm yes that could be intended . I do know another trick besides to multiply it out e.g. something like (untested) ´[Tt][Em]....ˋ

Comment: Do you mean to replace above statement as below:                                                                                               terminal stmt: '[Tt][Ee][Mm][Pp]' -> ';';                                                                                  It is not working.

Comment: Then I have no idea

Comment: Maybe (‚T‘|‘t‘)... ->

Comment: This would accept T E M P also instead of just TEMP.

Comment: cant reproduce that

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
terminal THINGY:
    ('T' | 't') ('E' | 'e')
    ('M' | 'm') ('P' | 'p')->";";
```